# resizing images so as they are the same size

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot and I am unable to resize my image. Can someone please help me?

I would like the images to be the same size. Here is my html:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<body class="body">

  <div class="wiesiek">
    <h1> Wiesiek Bland - My portfolio </h1>
    <h2> Warszawa Poland</h2>

    <div class="facebook, inline">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/wilyb"><img class="small-picture" src=http://static1.squarespace.com/static/4f5810d9e4b0ebbf0a1507a6/t/55a6e39be4b0e13bc07f93a1/1437000604121/></a>
    </div>
    <div class"github, inline">
      <a href="https://github.com/Wiesiek2811"><img class="small-picture" src=http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and here is my css:

```
.facebook {
  padding-left: 800px;
  max-width:
}

.github {
  width: 80px;
}

.inline {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/90wn844n/

HTML:

```
<div class="wiesiek">
<h1> Wiesiek Bland - My portfolio </h1>
<h2> Warszawa Poland</h2>

<div class="facebook inline">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/wilyb"><img class="small-picture" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/4f5810d9e4b0ebbf0a1507a6/t/55a6e39be4b0e13bc07f93a1/1437000604121/"></a>
</div>

 <div clas="github inline">
 <a href="https://github.com/Wiesiek2811"><img class="small-picture" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png"></a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook {
 padding-left: 800px;
}

.github {
width: 80px;
}

.inline {
float: left;
}

.small-picture {
  width: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image through by  html

by html tag

```
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png" height="500px" width="500px">
```

Comment: I would use css instead of inline styling.